# transparent background image link

Tags: html, css, background, hyperlink, transparent

How do i make my transparent gif image a link which the link won't respond if press the transparent part?

```
<a href="{storeurl}?act=viewDoc&docId=1"><img src="skins/sunlift/styleImages/navbar_pic/leafshape.gif></a>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: So, to make sure I have this right.  You want to have your anchor be an image with a transparent background, but you don't want the background to be clickable?

Answer (score 2):

```
<img src="skins/sunlift/styleImages/navbar_pic/leafshape.gif>
            here is the problem ----------------------------^-- there should be "
```

should be

```
 <img src="skins/sunlift/styleImages/navbar_pic/leafshape.gif">
```

Comment: I see.I changed it to 
   <a href ="{storeurl}?act=viewDoc&docId=1"><img src="skins/sunlift/styleImages/navbar_pic/leafshape.gif" /></a>
But it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

............................................................

hi now give to your **anchor** link `display` properties as like this

```
a{
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:top;
}
```

because `a` is `inline block` element

Comment: @Daedalus now check to a is inline block or inline-block http://www.tutorialchip.com/tutorials/inline-elements-list-whats-new-in-html5/    check to this link

Comment: Never use third-party tut sites as citations.  If you're going to cite something, it should be the [w3c specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/struct/links.html#edef-A).  Also, what you just said makes no sense, given I never disputed the existence of the dash, but rather the fact that you don't need to specify a default value.

Comment: @Daedalus now check to live demo i created u check and accept to this is inline element http://jsfiddle.net/jGUtH/

Comment: Your demo explains what your words cannot.